# How do I set width for a flex item with horizontal scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I am using `display: flex` to do a 3 column layout on desktop view.

However starting on `540px` and below, I still want the layout to be 3 columns but it should have a horizontal scroll. I was able to achieve horizontal scroll through `white-space: nowrap; overflow-x: auto;`. My problem is that I find each flex item or column too wide.

I want to show 1 or products on mobile view but put a horizontal scroll at the same time to scroll for the 3rd product.

Do you have any idea how can I set a width for each `flex-item` or `column`? By means of giving it a 150px or any depending on your idea. Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```css
.blog-articles-list {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow-x: unset;
  white-space: normal;
}

.blog-articles-list .flex-item {
  flex-basis: 33.33%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  .blog-articles-list {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="blog-articles-list">
    <div class="blog-article-info flex-item mb-40">
      <img class="image" src="//website/placeholder-join-the-movement-img_480x.jpg?v=1626159716">
      <div class="blog-article-detail">
        <div class="article-tag uppercase header-6 semi-bold color-green mb-5">campaigns</div> <a class="header-5 semi-bold" href="/blogs/articles/join-the-movement">Join the movement</a>
        <p class="rte color-black"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="blog-article-info flex-item mb-40">
      <img class="image" src="//website/placeholder-join-the-movement-img_480x.jpg?v=1626159716">
      <div class="blog-article-detail">
        <div class="article-tag uppercase header-6 semi-bold color-green mb-5">campaigns</div> <a class="header-5 semi-bold" href="/blogs/articles/join-the-movement">Join the movement</a>
        <p class="rte color-black"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-article-info flex-item mb-40">
      <img class="image" src="//website/placeholder-join-the-movement-img_480x.jpg?v=1626159716">
      <div class="blog-article-detail">
        <div class="article-tag uppercase header-6 semi-bold color-green mb-5">guides</div> <a class="header-5 semi-bold" href="/blogs/articles/how-to-lighten-pigmentation-naturally">How to lighten pigmentation naturally?</a>
        <p class="rte color-black"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you could use column instead of flex and give a definate width to it

Comment: the `nowrap` will prevent the line from breaking, thus making only a single line. Is that what's happening? You can achieve the horizontal scrolling only with `overflow-x:auto`

Comment: @SalilRajkarnikar Are you saying I should give it a flex-direction column or remove `display: flex` then give it's children a `display inline`?

Answer (score 4):

Simply add `flex-shrink:0` and `flex-basis:100%`

```css
.blog-articles-list {
  display: flex;
  overflow:auto;
}

.blog-articles-list .flex-item {
  flex-basis: 33.33%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  .blog-articles-list .flex-item {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="blog-articles-list">
    <div class="blog-article-info flex-item mb-40">
      <img class="image" src="//website/placeholder-join-the-movement-img_480x.jpg?v=1626159716">
      <div class="blog-article-detail">
        <div class="article-tag uppercase header-6 semi-bold color-green mb-5">campaigns</div> <a class="header-5 semi-bold" href="/blogs/articles/join-the-movement">Join the movement</a>
        <p class="rte color-black"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="blog-article-info flex-item mb-40">
      <img class="image" src="//website/placeholder-join-the-movement-img_480x.jpg?v=1626159716">
      <div class="blog-article-detail">
        <div class="article-tag uppercase header-6 semi-bold color-green mb-5">campaigns</div> <a class="header-5 semi-bold" href="/blogs/articles/join-the-movement">Join the movement</a>
        <p class="rte color-black"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-article-info flex-item mb-40">
      <img class="image" src="//website/placeholder-join-the-movement-img_480x.jpg?v=1626159716">
      <div class="blog-article-detail">
        <div class="article-tag uppercase header-6 semi-bold color-green mb-5">guides</div> <a class="header-5 semi-bold" href="/blogs/articles/how-to-lighten-pigmentation-naturally">How to lighten pigmentation naturally?</a>
        <p class="rte color-black"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not to sure about what you expect, it should not wrap below 540px and remain 3col with a scrollbar.

flex-basis:33.33% will shrink them and  is not enough, you'll need to set a min-width or reset flex-shrink.

Example with min-width and minimal code.

***But, please clarify about behavior expected below 540px and upper 541px.***

```css
.blog-articles-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow:auto;/* ?? here or at 540px */
}

.blog-articles-list .flex-item {
  flex-basis: 33.33%;

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  .blog-articles-list {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
.blog-articles-list .flex-item {
  min-width:50%
}
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="blog-articles-list">
    <div class="blog-article-info flex-item mb-40">
      <img class="image" src="//website/placeholder-join-the-movement-img_480x.jpg?v=1626159716">
      <div class="blog-article-detail">
        <div class="article-tag uppercase header-6 semi-bold color-green mb-5">campaigns</div> <a class="header-5 semi-bold" href="/blogs/articles/join-the-movement">Join the movement</a>
        <p class="rte color-black"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-article-info flex-item mb-40">
      <img class="image" src="//website/placeholder-join-the-movement-img_480x.jpg?v=1626159716">
      <div class="blog-article-detail">
        <div class="article-tag uppercase header-6 semi-bold color-green mb-5">events</div> <a class="header-5 semi-bold" href="/blogs/articles/should-you-wash-your-face-with-cold-water">Should you wash your face with cold water?</a>
        <p class="rte color-black"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-article-info flex-item mb-40">
      <img class="image" src="//website/placeholder-join-the-movement-img_480x.jpg?v=1626159716">
      <div class="blog-article-detail">
        <div class="article-tag uppercase header-6 semi-bold color-green mb-5">guides</div> <a class="header-5 semi-bold" href="/blogs/articles/how-to-lighten-pigmentation-naturally">How to lighten pigmentation naturally?</a>
        <p class="rte color-black"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hello. thanks for your response. i was hoping to show 1 or 2 products on mobile view but give it a horizontal scroll at the same time to scroll for the 3rd product.

Comment: okay, so the col should at least around 270px (or 50%) of width  if i understand your idea ? **snippet updated**